# Polyglot Anagrams Cops' Thread

Tags: code-golf, sequence, polyglot, cops-and-robbers

This challenge has two threads.  This is the cops' thread. The robbers' thread is located [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99156/polyglot-anagrams-robbers-thread).

Your challenge is to choose an [OEIS](https://oeis.org) sequence and write two *full programs* in two different languages that produces that nth item in the sequence when given an n via STDIN, or an other forms of standard input, where n is any positive number.  However your two programs must be anagrams, meaning each can be rearranged from the other's letters.

Programs must output the decimal of the number followed by optional whitespace to STDOUT.  Programs may output to STDERR however it should be ignored and if the hidden case does so it must be clearly stated that this is the case.

If you wish you may also output by character code.  However if you do so in your hidden solution you must state such in the body of your submission.

You will then present the OEIS number, the source code for and the name of *one* language it is in.

Robbers will crack your submission if they find an anagram of the original  submission that runs in a language other than the one you already presented.  To crack an answer they must only find ***any*** language and program which produces the sequence and is an anagram of the original, not necessarily the answer the you were thinking about.

Thus you are incentivized to make it as hard as possible to find any language that does the task using their list of symbols.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest un-cracked program is the winner.

### Languages

Languages will be considered different if the two proposed solutions do not complete the task in both languages.  This will include different versions of *the same language* as long as neither the cop's solution or the robber's solution produce the correct output in the other's language.

i.e. If the there are two solutions 1 and 2 that are in language A and B respectively solution 2 must not produce the correct output in language A and solution 1 must not produce the correct output in language B.

## Safety

Once your submission has been uncracked for a week you may post your solution and declare your post safe.  If after a week you choose not to post a solution your answer may still be cracked.

Comment: To browse through random OEIS sequences for ideas, go to **https://oeis.org/webcam**

Comment: How would it work with languages that like to use flags to the interpreter, such as perl? Are they disqualified? Are flags counted as part of the code? Are flags "free" (not included in code or divulged at all)?

Comment: Can the hidden program exit with an error (after producing the output)? Should that be indicated in the answer?

Comment: @LuisMendo That is fine but should be indicated.

Comment: @Emigna I would like for flags to be divulged if they are not standard flags for running in the language.

Comment: Grammar nitpick: "Cop's Thread" and "Robber's Thread" should be "Cops' Thread" and "Robbers' Thread"

Comment: @DrMcMoylex Seeing as I have already done that myself, It is certainly allowed I will update the question

Comment: I think you should include that in the text

Comment: [Some reading for writing CnR challenges.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10027/8478)

Comment: Is it allowed to input/output a character, and use their character code to represent the numbers?

Comment: @jimmy23013 No.

Comment: @WheatWizard I want to enter a java entry but can people just switch the names of the variables and call it a done deal?

Comment: @tuskiomi No they cannot.  The polyglot needs to be in *different* language.

Comment: If the crack doesn't print the exact output, but still a understandable format of the sequence, does it count?

Comment: @EasterlyIrk As long as both are proper formats they do not have to be the same

Comment: @WheatWizard :/ even if the output formats were known?

Comment: @EasterlyIrk what do you mean?

Comment: @WheatWizard it was different from the output format of the real crack and the output of the given code.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk yes that is still a valid crack

Comment: @WheatWizard oh well

Comment: Can it be output like `[<number>]`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48255/discussion-between-wheat-wizard-and-easterly-irk).

Comment: My Python submission is correct for the first 15 entries, but loses precision after that. The anagrammed solution has exactly the same problem. Can I keep it, mentioning that it's accurate to 15 terms? (I can't imagine that no other submissions lose precision at some point...)

Comment: @ETHproductions I assume that this is a floating point error, so I think that as long as you are specifying that it is looses precision and both solutions would work as intended given infinite floating precision you are ok.

Comment: Not sure if this would be helpful to anyone else but this highlights any remaining missing characters or any duplicated ones: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BQjxRK

Comment: It'd be nice if there was a stack snippet to show uncracked answers, oldest first.

Answer (score 15):

## <s>Python 2, 118 bytes, [A042545](https://oeis.org/A042545)</s> [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99395/12012)

```
i=input();s=1/(801**.5-28);a=[0,1]
for p in range(i):a+=[a[-2]+a[-1]*int(s)];s=1/(s-int(s))
print a[i]#,,,.//000fhlmo|
```

I didn't feel like implementing a trivial sequence, so I decided to go with my PPCG user ID. I wrote this in the other language first, which should give you a clue about what that language is, though I'd bet 100 dollars that this will be cracked in a golfing language before it's cracked in the intended other language.

**Note:** Due to floating-point precision errors, this is only accurate up to an input of 14. The intended solution is the same way.

### Intended solution, JavaScript (ES7)

```
for(i=prompt(),s=1/(801**.5-28),a=[1,0];i--;s=1/(s-n))
  n=s|0,a.unshift(a[1]+a[0]*n);
alert(a[0])  //#+2:[]giiiiinnpt
```

Works in pretty much the same way as the Python solution, though the sequence is stored largest-first rather than smallest-first due to the fact that JS does not support negative indexing.

Comment: I can't get the case of A042545(15) to work. OEIS says that it is 53000053, but your program says that it is 27666361 (at least on my machine).

Comment: @boboquack The output for `16` is actually 53000053, but after that there doesn't seem to be any matching terms. I wonder why...

Comment: Maybe a floating point error that gets progressively worse?

Comment: Maybe try codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48320/discussion-between-ethproductions-and-boboquack).

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99395/12012)

Comment: Dammit, I was right! :( This was as close as I got: https://gist.github.com/dom111/bd9be933cb8ccd0e303601bf73d525b6 Thanks for the workout anyway, I needed `|()` but just couldn't get them!

Answer (score 10):

## Brain-Flak, 24 bytes, [A000290](http://oeis.org/A000290), Safe

Yet another square solution. This time there is nothing but parentheses

```
({(({}[()])()){}[()]}{})
```

---

The intended solution was in [Brain-Flueue](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Brain-Flueue), a version of brain-flak that uses queues instead of stacks.  The program was:

```
({(({})[()]){}}{})[()()]
```

The languages are considered distinct because neither of the two programs halt when run in the other language.

Comment: This would work in Glypho if input/output using character code is allowed...

Comment: @jimmy23013 what is Glypho?

Comment: http://esolangs.org/wiki/Glypho `((([{}{}{]]}[)))((){))(}`

Comment: @WheatWizard If it's cracked, can you edit the answer to show that?

Comment: @mbomb007 It is not cracked

Comment: @WheatWizard And why isn't jimmy's comment a crack? It works, doesn't it?

Comment: @mbomb007 It uses character codes rather than integers.  It does perform the square but does not fit the specs

Comment: Outputting a character as a "byte value" is allowed. A brainfuck solution, for example, is allowed to take input as a byte, and output as a byte, even though the output appears as a character. I've done it on challenges before. http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4719/34718

Comment: @mbomb007 I have already been very specific about the I/O on this challenge.  While I do respect the consensus of the meta I do not believe that this is a typical challenge.

Comment: @jimmy23013 http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4719/34718

Comment: @mbomb007 It's understandable to override the default in this challenge. So I asked in a comment to this question. It's better to edit that into the question though.

Comment: Also, the spec in the only listed interpreter is different than what the esolangs page says. http://esoteric.voxelperfect.net/files/glypho/doc/glypho.txt

Answer (score 7):

## <s>Python 2, 38 bytes, [A000290](http://oeis.org/A000290)</s> [Cracked by Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99156/polyglot-anagrams-robbers-thread/99163#99163)

```
def e(X):return X*X
print e(input())##
```

This will probably be very easy to crack. I'm mostly posting this as a starting point.

Orignial solution in CJam:

```
ri:XX*e#def ()return X
e#pnt (input())
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99163/47066)

Answer (score 7):

## <s>[CJam](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 7 bytes, [A005843](http://oeis.org/A005843)</s> [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99156/polyglot-anagrams-robbers-thread/99198#99198)

```
ri2*e#^
```

This is a basic `2*n` sequence.

Explanation:

```
r          e# read input
 i         e# convert to integer
  2*       e# multiply it by 2
    e#^    e# this is a comment that is ignored by the interpreter
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cmkyKmUjXg&input=MjE)

---

## Original Solution, [Carrot](https://github.com/kritixilithos/Carrot)

```
#^i*2er
```

Carrot is an esolang created by me. I have stopped developing it a long time ago. The reason I chose this is because I hoped that it would be hard for other languages to comment out the unnecessary parts of the code.

Explanation:

```
#^            This pushes the input to the stack (anything before the ^ is the stack)
  i           Convert stack to integer
   *2         Multiply it by 2
     er       These are ignored because they are not Carrot commands
              Implicit output
```

[Try it online!](http://kritixilithos.github.io/Carrot/)

Comment: `ri#e^*2` would work in Jelly if `*` were multiplication instead of exponentiation. So close...

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99198/34388) :).

Comment: I had everything but the `r` in pyth. Exciting to see the original code for this one.

Comment: @Emigna I added the original code

Answer (score 6):

## <s>Brain-Flak, 44 bytes, [A000290](http://oeis.org/A000290)</s> [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99166/56656)

```
<({({})({}[()])}{}))()()()turpentine/"*"*4splint>
```

[Try it online!](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/#code=PCh7KHt9KSh7fVsoKV0pfXt9KSgpKCkoKXR1cnBlbnRpbmUvIioiKjRzcGxpbnQ-Cg&input=NA&debug=on)

---

### Original solution, Python 2

```
print(input()**(len(set("{}{}{}[]()<>"))/4))
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99166/34388) :)

Comment: Now I'm really curious. What was your original intended solution? I can tell it's python because I see `len` `set` `input` and `print` (and because I know you like python) but I can't figure out how that squares a number

Comment: @DrMcMoylex added

Answer (score 6):

## <s>[2sable](http://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable), 15 bytes, [A000290](http://oeis.org/A000290)</s>, [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99237/31957)

Hopping on the same **n<sup>2</sup>** train :p.

```
*?"!#$&<=@\^{|}
```

[Try it online!](http://2sable.tryitonline.net/#code=Kj8iISMkJjw9QFxee3x9&input=NA)

Comment: Almost looks like Malbodge with the symbols in order like that :P

Comment: [Cracked :D](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99237/31957)

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Hahaha, I was pretty certain this wasn't possible in Jelly, Pyth, 05AB1E and MATL. Nice job! :)

Answer (score 5):

## <s>Excel, 12 bytes, [A000012](http://oeis.org/A000012)</s> [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99207/47066)

```
=IF(1=1,1,1)
```

Maybe not the toughest, but a fun one to crack.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99207/47066)

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, 25 bytes, [A000583](https://oeis.org/A000583), [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99278/45941)

```py
Y=input("");print`Y**4`,X
```

This program exits with an error after printing the output.

---

My hidden code (substantially different from the cracked solution!):

### [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 25 bytes

```
4,n`*`Y")ii(*nppruttY;="X
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=NCxuYCpgWSIpaWkoKm5wcHJ1dHRZOz0iWA&input=NTA)

Explanation:

```
4,n`*`Y")ii(*nppruttY;="X
4,n                        input, repeat 4 times
   `*`Y                    do * until the stack stops changing (fixed-point combinator)
       ")ii(*nppruttY;="X  push this string and immediately pop and discard it
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99278/34388)

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, 124 bytes, [A144945](http://oeis.org/A144945), [Safe]

Cracking this would have earned you a 500 rep bounty! Too late!

> Number of ways to place 2 queens on an n X n chessboard so that they attack each other.

I hope it's not too easy. I arranged my code so the whitespace is clearly visible. Those are spaces and newlines only.

<sub>*Note: intended solution outputs via character code*</sub>

```python
n=input();print((3+2)*n*n+~0*6*n+1)*n/3;            +6;



























+7+7+7+7+7+7+7+7+7;+++++++++++++++9+9*9*9
```

[**Try it online**](https://repl.it/EU0M/1)

#### Intended Solution, [Headsecks](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Headsecks):

```
r2=ni***p**
(
 
 
p((0 ;3+++3;+;/
 
 
)
 
 
 
 
 
i+++nn
 +)7
n
 
n+++ 
 
 
17+~
 +)7;97++++7
 
 
69+9n+ ++7+n 69
 +7+ ++7
 
 
**7+++tut
```

This is equivalent to the following BF program:

```
>>,[->>>+>>>+>>>+++++<<<<<<<<<]>>>->>>>>>-<<<[[>+<-]>[>>[<<<+>>+>-]<[>+<-]<-]<<<<]>>+++>[-<-[<+<<]<[+[->+<]<+<<]>>>>>]<<<.,.
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python, 118 bytes, [A042545](https://oeis.org/A042545), Safe

```
i=int(input());s=pow(801.0,0.5);a=[0|0,1]
for Moshprtflmah in range(i):s=1./(s%1);a+=[a[-2]+a[-1]*int(s)];
print(a[i])
```

This time it works in both 2 and 3. And there's no comments! What will you do?

Note: As with the old solution, this loses precision after the first 15 terms due to floating-point arithmetic errors.

### Intended solution, JavaScript (ES6)

```
giiiiinnnnprt:
i=prompt([n=+2]);s=Math.pow(801,.5);for(a=[1,0];i--;a.unshift(a[1]+a[0]*(s|0)))s=1/(s%1)
alert(a[0])
```

Though I kept several old versions, I somehow managed to lose *this* copy, but fortunately piecing it together from the others wasn't too hard. I see now that I had an extraneous `prt` in both programs that could have been golfed out. Oh well.

Comment: I thought I would remind you that you can mark this as safe if you wish.

Comment: @WheatWizard Thanks, I've added my intended solution.

Answer (score 4):

## Fuzzy Octo Guacamole, 26 bytes, [A070627](https://oeis.org/A070627) [Safe]

```
49++*5^pm#]%:"?:.=:#,|"1:@
```

Test cases:

```
1 -> 1
3 -> 23
5 -> 1
```

Solution:

```
^::::|*?1=#@]","%.#49++5pm
```

Works in Magistack.

Comment: Hello! Just reminding you that this answer can be marked as safe.  No need to rush but no one has cracked it in a week.  Good job, I am eager to see a solution

Comment: Cool, I'll do it and the other once when I get home.

Answer (score 3):

## <s>Python 2, 37 bytes, [A000290](http://oeis.org/A000290)</s> [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99172/47066)

```python
print(input()**(1+1))
"'10°3¢','m'"
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99172/47066)

Answer (score 3):

## MATL, 7 bytes, [A000217](https://oeis.org/A000217), [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99253/36398)

```
:sp{1}x
```

The sequence is `n(n+1)/2` (triangular numbers), starting at input `n=1` as specified by the challenge: `1`, `3`, `6`, `10`, ... (Output for input `0` is not guaranteed to be the same in the two programs).

The program in the other language exits with an error (after producing the correct output in STDOUT).

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OnNwezF9eA&input=MTA)

```
:            % Push [1 2 ... n], where n is implicit input
 s           % Sum of that array. Gives the desired result
   p         % Product of that. Gives the same number
    {1}      % Push a cell array containing number 1
       x     % Delete it
```

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99253/55696)

Comment: @StevenH.Well done! My original solution was `x:ps{}1`

Answer (score 3):

## [Fuzzy Octo Guacamole](https://github.com/RikerW/Fuzzy-Octo-Guacamole), 11 bytes, [A001844](http://oeis.org/A001844) [Safe!]

```
hha02^d+**+
```

[A crack that sort-of works is `dh*h++^2*0a`, in Pyth.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99156/polyglot-anagrams-robbers-thread/99252#99252) It's not the right output format though.

My code is still out there! (and it's not in Pyth)

Test Cases:

```
0 -> 1
1 -> 5
```

Solution:

```
^++d0ah*2*h
```

In Jolf.

Comment: I swear, this looks like it was made for Jolf, but I just can't figure out that `d`...

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99252/42545) (I hope...)

Comment: @ETHproductions ah, nice. Not sure if it counts though? See edit.

Comment: My code prints a newline, but no space. Same with the valid code.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk Despite what I said I do not consider the answer provided a crack.  I everything I said still holds true however I do not consider leading whitespace valid output and I will amend the question to reflect that.

Comment: @ETHproductions ^

Comment: @WheatWizard OK, I've deleted my post.

Comment: This answer can also be marked as safe at your own disgression.

Answer (score 3):

## <s>Pyth, 75 bytes, [A004526](https://oeis.org/A00526)</s> [Cracked, milk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99156/polyglot-anagrams-robbers-thread/99263#99263)

More of a playful test than anything, but:

```
/Q/////////////////****22222 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2;;;;;
```

[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2FQ%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2a%2a%2a%2a22222+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B&input=129&debug=0)

Milk's solution (Convex):

```
2/Q2 2/2/2/2/2/2/2/2/2/2/2/2/2/2/2/2/2/2*2*2*; 2*;                 2; 2; 2;
```

[Try it online](http://convex.tryitonline.net/#code=Mi9RMiAyLzIvMi8yLzIvMi8yLzIvMi8yLzIvMi8yLzIvMi8yLzIvMioyKjIqOyAyKjsgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDI7IDI7IDI7&input=Nw)

Intended solution (///):

```
/*///;2/;// ///22/Q//2;///;//;***2222222222222222222222
```

[Try it online](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=LyovLy87Mi87Ly8gLy8vMjIvUS8vMjsvLy87Ly8yMjIyMjIyOyoqKjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIA&input=)

Takes input in the form of 2's before the last semicolon and outputs the correct number of Q's.

The sequence is 0-indexed (i.e. 0 is 0, 1 is 0, 2 is 1, ...)

Found slight syntactical mistakes in the ///, so edited all solutions.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99263/58106)

Answer (score 3):

## <s>Python 3, 27 bytes, [A000012](https://oeis.org/A000012)</s>, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99156/polyglot-anagrams-robbers-thread/99360#99360)

No input this time!

```
if 1:
    if 1:
        print( '1' )
```

The indents are tabs, but not to save bytes - they are required for whitespace.

I don't think it needs a TIO link or explanation!

(Probably won't take long to crack in some way)

Intended answer (Whitespace):

```
-Start-
    
    
    if1:if1:print('1')
-End-
```

(Start and end not part of the program)

Sorry, I forgot to add that it prints to STDERR:

[Try it online!](http://whitespace.tryitonline.net/#code=ICAgCQoJCiAJaWYxOmlmMTpwcmludCgnMScp&input=)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99360/58106).

Comment: I feel like this is supposed to be Whitespace, but that would print an error to STDERR as it's lacking the required linefeeds to end in [LF][LF][LF].

Comment: @milk Not you again! :D

Comment: @boboquack It does work, but it *does* print to STDERR (which you can see by activating the Debug mode on TIO), and the challenge says that answers need to specify whether the hidden language writes to STDERR.

Comment: [Cracked again.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99388/12537)

Comment: @Oliver can't find your crack...

Comment: @boboquack I deleted it as it has already been cracked.

Answer (score 2):

## <s>[MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 13 bytes, [A002275](http://oeis.org/A002275)</s>  [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99226/31716)

```
i:"@ax'1']
v!
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=aToiQGF4JzEnXQp2IQ&input=)

Explanation:

```
i           % Grab input
 :          % Push (range(1,input))
  "         % For each element in this range:
   @        %   Push it
    a       %   Is is truthy?
     x      %   Delete it
      '1'   %   Push '1'
         ]  %   End loop
v           % Join all of these '1's together
 !          % Transpose and display
```

Comment: I feel like this is in Vim but for the life of me I can't crack it

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99226/56656) :)

Answer (score 2):

## <s>WinDbg, 39 bytes, [A000007](https://oeis.org/A000007)</s> [Cracked by jimmy23013](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99156/polyglot-anagrams-robbers-thread/99213#99213)

```
~e.block{j(0>=@$t0)?@$t0+(1<7);??0}t":"
```

The difficult sequence of `0**n`.

Input is done by passing a value in the pseudo-register `$t0`.

My original solution was C#:

```
@t=>(object)(0<@t?0:1)??"$$700~lk.{}+";
```

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99213/25180)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES6, 38 bytes, [A000290](http://oeis.org/A000290), [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99244/31957)

```
J=>eval(Array(J).fill(J).join`+`)|2-2;
```

This square train is pretty nifty, but isn't going anywhere fast. (Get it? *square* train? as in, wheels? no? okay, fine. *critics*.)

---

Intended answer: Reticular ([Try it online!](http://reticular.tryitonline.net/#code=aW4ySm87PT5ldmFsKEFycmF5KEopLmZpbGwoSikuamArYCl8LTI&input=Ng)),

```
in2Jo;=>eval(Array(J).fill(J).j`+`)|-2
in      take input, convert to number
  2J    raise to the second power
    o;  output and terminate; ignores following chars
```

Comment: Your code is trying to convince me that the other language is J :P

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99244/56656).

Answer (score 2):

## <s>[2sable](http://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable), 13 bytes, [A002378](https://oeis.org/A002378)</s>, [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99286/8478)

Hoping I didn't miss something. Computes **a(n) = n × (n + 1)**:

```
>*?"!&)<=@\\}
```

---

My version:

```
?"\>@&*})<\=!
```

Or the unfolded version:

```
  ? " \
 > @ & *
} ) < \ =
 ! . . .
  . . .
```

Note that the `>` in the top-left corner is unused (except for the 2sable program). I did this to confuse the robbers (but that obviously didn't work haha).

[Try it online!](http://2sable.tryitonline.net/#code=Pio_IiEmKTw9QFxcfQ&input=Ng)

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99286/8478) :)

Comment: @MartinEnder Nice job! I'll update my answer with the original submission :).

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 35 bytes, [A048735](http://oeis.org/A048735), Safe

```
print(lambda u:u&u<<1)(input())>>1
```

---

The original solution was in my own programming language [Wise](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Wise).

```
:<<>&>print(lambda uuu1)(input())1
```

Most of the characters are irrelevant no-ops.  The important characters are the first six. `:` creates two copies of the first item on the stack.  `<<>` bit shifts twice to the left and once to the right which is equivalent to bit shifting once to the left.  `&` takes the bitwise and of the top and second item (the original and the bit shifted copy).  Lastly `>` bit shifts once to the right.

Answer (score 2):

## 05AB1E, 5 bytes, [A000012](https://oeis.org/A000012), Safe

```
$;$1?
```

Sequence of 1's. [Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=JDskMT8&input=ODY)

#### Intended Solution: Arcyou

```
1;$$?
```

[Try it online](http://arcyou.tryitonline.net/#code=MTskJD8&input=NTQ). I couldn't find documentation for this language, so don't have an explanation of how it works exactly.

Comment: Stupid semicolon... I could almost use Retina, but I can't have both the `1` and `;`.

Comment: This has not been cracked

Comment: It looks like this answer can now be marked as safe.  Since I spent quite a deal of time trying to crack this one I am quite eager to see the intended answer.

Comment: Shouldn't this answer be marked as "accepted" now?

Answer (score 2):

## <strike>[Befunge 93](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html), 14 bytes, [A121377](https://oeis.org/A121377),</strike>  [Cracked by milk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99398/42854)!

```
&52* %68*+ .@Q
```

Fun fact: The intended solution to this is the first time I've ever used that language.

My solution in Pyth. &@ print an error, but that goes to STDERR which according to the OP is ignored.

```
+%Q*5 2*6 8.&@
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99398/58106)

Answer (score 2):

## 2sable, 15 bytes, [A087156](https://oeis.org/A087156)

```
D1QiA0*<}.;2->>
```

[Try it online](http://2sable.tryitonline.net/#code=RDFRaUEwKjx9LjsyLT4-&input=Nw)

The sequence of non-negative numbers, except for 1.

Answer (score 1):

## <s>Python 2, 70 Bytes, [A000217](https://oeis.org/A000217)</s> [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99210/25180)

I have a feeling this won't be cracked in the language I used for the other version, we will see :)

```python
o=input()
v=0
i=1
while o:
 v+=i
 i+=1
print v


#|  d00->1@@@++-^,,[
```

---

I realized afterwards I had incorrectly obfuscated the code (it doesn't change the posted answer's validity). Here's the code I started with in Haystack:

```
v
0
v
0
i
1
-
>      d0[v
^-1@+@d+1@?,,o|
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99210/25180).

Answer (score 1):

## <s>[05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes, [A000042](http://oeis.org/A000042)</s> [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99156/polyglot-anagrams-robbers-thread/99329#99329)

```
1×,1*-^$)
```

This is the *Unary representation of natural numbers* (OEIS). So if the input was `3`, for example, then output would be `111`.

Explanation:

```
                    # implicit input
1                   # pushes 1 to the stack   
 ×                  # pushes "1" × (the input)
  ,                 # outputs the stack
   1*-^$)           # irrelevant
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=McOXLDEqLV4kKQ&input=Nw)

---

## Original Solution, [Carrot](https://github.com/kritixilithos/Carrot)

```
1^*$-1×^)
```

Explanation

```
1^             Push "1" to the stack
  *            Multiply the string by
   $-1         ...the input (as an integer) minus 1 times
      ×,)      Ignored by the interpreter
```

The `*` multiplies the string by `(n+1)` times, so that `a^*3` results in `aaaa` and not `aaa`. So that is why I subtracted `1` from the input.

Only now I realise that the `)` has been irrelevant in both the languages :D

[Try it online!](http://kritixilithos.github.io/Carrot/)

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99329/12537)

Comment: What was the original hidden language?

Comment: @WheatWizard Whoops, thanks for finding that. I added the language now

Answer (score 1):

## 05AB1E, 8 bytes, [A000042](https://oeis.org/A000042), [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99348/41805)

```
F1}J,(1&
```

Test cases:

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 11
3 -> 111
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99348/41805)

Answer (score 1):

## J, 2 bytes, [A000290](http://oeis.org/A000290), [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99379/31957)

```
*~
```

Well, might as well start going for those two-byters. Yields **n** × **n**, or **n**<sup>2</sup>.

### <s>intended solution, Jolf, 2 bytes</s>

```
*~
```

Well. Yeah. This is my own language and I think it works because `~` looks for an extended character, but doesn't find one, so it just ignores it. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Oops.

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99379/55696)

Comment: @StevenH. nice job! I edited with intended solution.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien your intended solution was not a valid solution.  In order for languages to be considered distinct neither the original or the solution can be a polyglot in both languages

Comment: @WheatWizard Oh. That's awkward.

Answer (score 1):

## <s>[ABCR](https://github.com/Steven-Hewitt/ABCR), 24 bytes, [A023443](https://oeis.org/A023443)</s> [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99394/55696)

```
70: Quit xi. Classy queue!
```

There's a bunch of no-ops.  Calculates `n - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

### <s>[Ouroboros](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Ouroboros), 6 bytes, [A000012](https://oeis.org/A000012)</s> [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99468/42545)

```
)49.o(
```

Always outputs `1`.

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99468/42545)

Comment: @DLosc sorry for posting in the wrong place but you haven't been on chat in ages ;_;

Answer (score 1):

## 05AB1E, 5 bytes, [A005843](http://oeis.org/A005843)

```
ApDF>
```

Calculates `n*2`.

Comment: This is NOT cracked because I just found out that my crack was invalid. I have deleted it now because it is invalid since the original program was a polyglot in 05AB1E/2sable.

Answer (score 0):

## <s>05AB1E, 5 bytes, [A000012](https://oeis.org/A000012)</s> [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99156/polyglot-anagrams-robbers-thread/99466#99466)

```
¸WW/`
```

The funny thing is that the cracked version is the intended answer.

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=wrhXVy9g&input=MTMzNA)

Comment: It outputs nothing when the input is `0`

Comment: And it outputs `21` when input is `42` [Here](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=V1cvw68&input=NDI)

Comment: @KritixiLithos There.

Comment: Now it outputs `1.0` instead of `1`

Comment: @KritixiLithos It's the same thing.

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99466/41805) :)